# Adding files to a node

Tags: 7, files

I am adding files to a file field in my node object.  Do I have to specify a path for the file(s)?  Can't I just add the files to the DB and just add the file objects to the node? I'd rather let Drupal care about the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to specify a folder, file field will use 'sites/default/files' by default. In the file field settings there is a textfield to set a subfolder if needed.

Comment: Is it smart enough, if it has to use the file system, to keep file names unique?

Comment: yes, it should keep filenames unique.